# Wrong Confirmation Key error when click on confirmation link

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento CE 1.9.2.3 and enable email confirmation for registration. Email is sent as normal, but when I click the link, it always fails. The link is like this

> https://domain.com/customer/account/confirm/?id=10&key=1fdc9eb4eb591cfaef5878b907348587

Later on, I found out that under customer_entity_varchar table, Magento stores the plain text (from the password) instead of the hash string, under attribute_id 16 (confirmation). When I change this plain text to the hash string, it works.

My question is, why Magento stores the plain text whilst email the hash string?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. The culprit was Webkul Vendor Attributes extension which overwrite Magento default values and stored password and password_confirmation in plain text. Really really dangerous!

Comment: There is no overwrite in default values also there is no attribute for password field as well . Please let us know at https://webkul.com/ticket and we will look in to it thanks

Comment: All your extensions have a lot of bugs! I mean really really a lot! Very frustrating!

Comment: Opening a ticket with you guys won't help because all you guys have in mind is money, money and money. It's useless talking with such kind of people.